# sum of specific elements in normalized value count in pandas (KNN Classification)

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, count, knn

I am trying some knn-Classification and when testing the model with 30% of the original data,

I want to calculate the percentage of correct classification within a +/-3 point range (left side in below output).

In other words the sum of the seven floats at the bottom of the below output:

```
 18    0.000028
 15    0.000028
 14    0.000083
 13    0.000193
-11    0.000276
 12    0.000634
-10    0.000689
-9     0.001019
 11    0.001323
-8     0.002976
 10    0.003141
 9     0.005097
-7     0.006833
 8     0.009093
 7     0.012702
-6     0.013005
 6     0.020941
-5     0.021905
-4     0.036646
 5     0.036674
 4     0.055713
-3     0.058965
 3     0.087896
-2     0.088777
-1     0.116166
 2     0.119031
 1     0.142893
 0     0.157276
```

To be precise the sum of these floats:

```
-3     0.058965
 3     0.087896
-2     0.088777
-1     0.116166
 2     0.119031
 1     0.142893
 0     0.157276
```

Which would be 0,771004

So how do I make Python add only those values together?

Important is, that **these values are not always the seven at the bottom**, but may be spread around, depending on the chosen value for k.

I think my problem is that I have the logic for sorting and summing up mixed up.

This output is generated by this command:

```
perc_pred_dev = check_test_series['deviation_from_tru'].value_counts(sort=True, ascending=True, normalize=True)
print(perc_pred_dev)
```

- check_test_series is a dataframe with info necessary to check accuracy
- deviation_from_tru is the difference between original value and prediction by the model.

Answer (score 0):

You can lose the sort because it is un needed, but in any case you should sum by index:

```
df.loc[-3:0]['0'].sum()
```

assuming df is your dataframe and '0' is the name of the column